# object is not iterable. How can I make this code work

Tags: python-3.x

Can someone help me to solve this issue why it returns this error:
object is not iterable.

```
def leap_year(start_year, end_year):
    for start_year in end_year:
        # Leap Year Check
        if start_year % 4 == 0 and start_year % 100 != 0:
            print(start_year, "is a Leap Year")
        elif start_year % 100 == 0:
            print(start_year, "is not a Leap Year")
        elif start_year % 400 ==0:
            print(start_year, "is a Leap Year")
        else:
            print(start_year, "is not a Leap Year")
        if end_year % 4 == 0 and end_year % 100 != 0:
            print(end_year, "is a Leap Year")
        elif end_year % 100 == 0:
            print(end_year, "is not a Leap Year")
        elif end_year % 400 ==0:
            print(end_year, "is a Leap Year")
        else:
            print(end_year, "is not a Leap Year")

leap_year(2000, 2006)
```

Comment: `for start_year in end_year` does not make sense. You have to supply it a range of some sort, if I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Seems like home work. Here some tips, assuming that you are trying to find a leap year within the **range** that has been submitted as arguments (that highlight was the first hint). You seem to want to iterate over a range and check for every year in that range whether it is a leap year. Google 'python range for loop'.

Comment: yes correct, I want to iterate the range i pass as arguments. but I just get brain freeze of this :/ thanks I will try google python range for loop

Answer (score 0):

your input for end_year is 2006 which is a number not an iterable.

you need to make end_year an iterable if you want to iterate through it

ie `for start_year in end_year`

to make end_year an iterable you can try `range(end_year)`

ie `for start_year in range(end_year)`

will leave it to you to look up the range function